# Tomcat connector for Internet Information Server not working

Tags: iis, tomcat, ajp

I am trying to configure a Internet Information Server to work with Tomcat and after following the steps in [the website](https://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/webserver_howto/iis.html) it's does not work.

What is worst, no way to document or to realize where the problem is. As appear in the website there are many steps to configure and the output should be "ok", but there is no way to diagnose where the problem is.

**IIS**

I have a windows Server 2012 R2 64 bits with the IIS that comes out with the installation. First question: ¿is it 32bit or 64bit??? For the rest of this question I will assume it's 64 bit.

**Tomcat**

Apache tomcat 10.0.18. Runs with java version 1.8.0_161. The server is configured to run as a service with logon as "Local System account". For the sake of this example, let's say is installed in `%TOMCAT_HOME%`.

AJP connector configured like this:

```
<Connector protocol="AJP/1.3"
           address="0.0.0.0"
           port="8009"
           secretRequired="false"
           xpoweredBy="true"/>
```

And confirmed it's working:

```
C:\>netstat -ab | find "8009"
  TCP    0.0.0.0:8009           THIS-SERVER:0        LISTENING
  TCP    [::]:8009              THIS-SERVER:0        LISTENING
```

**ISAPI redirector for Micrsoft IIS**

Downloaded [from here](https://dlcdn.apache.org/tomcat/tomcat-connectors/jk/binaries/). 64bit version. Installed under `%TOMCAT_HOME%\isapi`. Config files are:

`ìsapi_redirect.properties`:

```
#
# isapi_redirect.properties
#

extension_uri=/jakarta/isapi_redirect.dll

log_file=[server-home-removed]\\isapi\\isapi_redirect.log

log_level=debug

worker_file=[server-home-removed]\\isapi\\workers.properties

worker_mount_file=[server-home-removed]\\isapi\\uriworkermap.properties
```

`workers.properties`

```
#
# workers.properties
#

worker.list=tomcat01

worker.tomcat01.type=ajp13
worker.tomcat01.host=localhost
worker.tomcat01.port=8009
```

`uriworkermap.properties`

```
#
# uriworkermap.properties
#

/examples/*=tomcat01
/jakarta/*=tomcat01
/pwdReset/*=tomcat01
```

**Configuration of the IIS tried**

1. I've given permission to the `isapi` directory as requested by the manual:

   icacls "%TOMCAT_HOME%\isapi" /grant "IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool":(OI)(CI)M

   icacls "%TOMCAT_HOME%\isapi\isapi_redirect.dll" /grant "Everyone":RX
2. I've created a f**** virtual directory (this is the third or fourth time I do) named "jakarta" and point it to the later directory (see below). The virtual directory has the "connect as" property configured as "application user (pass-through authentication)":

[image]

3. Handler mapping configured as follows:

[image]

Access request restrictions configured as "none". But I've tried also with "execute" and nothing happens.

4. ISAPI filter config:

[image]

**The problem is** that apparently having everything ok, the output I got when trying to connect to the virtual path is a 500 error if I use the ISAPI filter of 32 bits or 403 error if I use the 64 bit ISAPI filter.  What am I doing wrong??? And what's more important, is there a way to diagnose that the different parts of this clusterfuck are correct, to check if the ISAPI filter is working, the AJP connector of tomcat is working, etc.???

[image]

Comment: I've found that I have to configure DefaultAppPool "Enable 32-bit Applications" to False, but it seems that this not solves the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Solved: if you read [the updated reference of the connector](https://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/reference/iis.html) you will find several things:

> Note that in a 64 Bit environment - at least for IIS 7 - **the used IIS
> Application Pool should have "Enable 32-bit Applications" set to
> "False"**. Otherwise the redirector will not be called and returns an
> http code 404. If you think, the 32bit version of isapi_redirect.dll
> would do the job instead, you will get an http code 500, because the
> library is not loadable into a 64 Bit IIS.

And I've completed the registry information prior to test again. Now it is working (requests appear in the tomcat side).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/httpplatformhandler/info Microsoft only supports Java apps via HttpPlatformHandler.